# Can someone recommend a ROM and kernel for the Galaxy S2 that works fully?

Tags: rom, kernel

I have installed a kernel and ROM onto my Samsung Galaxy S2. However, it's been giving me a lot of problems. First the Compass didn't work, then when the compass was fixed by installing a patch the WiFi stopped working, then when I reinstalled the ROM to get Wifi back, I lost the compass again...

I very much appreciate all the efforts that people who make kernels and ROMs put into it, and I understand that sometimes errors and problems can't be helped. So this is not a complaint.

It's just that I'd like to wipe my phone, start clean, and install a kernel and/or ROM that I can be sure will work.

I've already learned how to flash and install kernels and ROMs, and I've got my purchased version of Titanium Backup ready so I can reinstall all my apps...

Just before I go through the whole effort, I'd like to be sure that the kernel and ROM I'm using are as certain to be fully functional and error free as one can hope.

So can someone recommend a kernel and ROM that I can or should use?

Note: Here is what I have now:

Model number: GT-I9100

Android version: 4.0.4

Baseband version: SC02COMKL4

Kernel version: 3.0.27-Siyah-v3.0.1-ntt

Comment: Apart from the obvious - what's wrong with stock ROM (everything works) and Siyah Kernel? You're obviously rooted, so you can then use Titanium Backup and freeze the bloatware.

Comment: Leading contenders will be CyanogenMod 9 which just underwent code freeze so RCs will be out soon, MIUI ROM, HydrogenICS, SlimICS and WanamLite

Comment: @Sparx: Nothing wrong with it, I just didn't know it was an option. I know a bit about flashing ROMs from having been through the process, but I'm hardly an expert. Where would I get a "stock" ROM? And if I use a "stock" ROM, will I still have root access?

Comment: @Sparx: Thank you for the recommendations. However, I've just tried Googling a bit, and I'm not sure exactly what the difference is or where exactly to download. Any chance of a more firm recommendation or breakdown of the differences? Also, are these all ROMs? Is my kernel okay and should I only be looking at ROMs?

Comment: For the interested: CM9 nightlies already exist http://get.cm/?device=galaxys2&type=nightly

Comment: A big issue in the ROM community is the heavy focus on customization at the price of stability and functionality. I have an awesome SGS2 with a great ROM, it's just that Bluetooth hardly ever works and WiFi will refuse to be turned on every other day. But I get a new boot animation with every update of this ROM! :)

Comment: @ce4: Aren't "nightlies" unstable? I thought "nightly" meant they were the versions being developed and worked on.

Comment: ROM recommendations are shopping recommendations, and thus not a good fit for this site.

Comment: @AlEverett: Except I am not looking for recommendations of just "good" or "better". My current ROM has had specific issues: WiFi, compass, and GPS issues. So is it not specific enough to be looking for a ROM that does not have those issues?

Comment: I suppose, since there are specific issues you're looking to solve.

Comment: WiFi issues are related to the kernel. The latest Siyah kernel is 3.3.1 for the S2. The dev has now frozen further feature releases for the S2 kernel in order to focus on the S3. The other names are indeed all ROMs. I have stuck with the stock ROM because everything works. I have a replacement homescreen launcher. There are replacement apps for the phone dialer, contacts, SMS, camera etc. Install those and see if they help.

Comment: One more thing - most, if not all, ROMs are in continuous development, so they keep fixing bugs and adding/removing/modifying features. Manufacturer or stock ROMs merely tend to be more complete. There's a thread on XDA for stock S2 ROMs. Flash the latest available one for your region and try it out for a week or two.

Comment: @Sparx: It seems there's one more update for the S2 kernel, it's at 3.3.2 now. I've installed that. Also, one more question about the stock ROM. The whole reason I rooted and installed a custom ROM was to remove bloatware and release myself from my carrier's USB tethering charges. If I install the stock ROM, will that not include bloatware and also revert me back to the USB tethering system that was in place before?

Comment: I'm unsure about whether an unlocked "international" ROM would work with your carrier (it should, IMHO). It *would* include all the bloatware that Samsung did include but like I mentioned above - freeze them using Ti Backup. I'm not well versed with US carriers, being from India myself. Try posting in XDA for more competent advice. Sorry.

Comment: Dave, if you root you can remove the bloatware from a stock ROM.  Unfortunately though this still falls under our ban on recommendations.  If you wanted to rewrite this to ask "How can I solve <specific issue(s)>" that would be OK though.  Another option is to ask in chat.

Comment: You mentioned compass issues. What patch did you use? Do you have the Korean version of the GSG2?